# Perf stat doesn't count events when using delay switch

Tags: linux, performance, optimization, x86, perf

I am trying to profile my application 20 seconds after starting because I'm not interested in the initialization stage.

So I used `perf` with the delay (microseconds) switch:

```
sudo perf stat --delay=20000 -e page-faults my_app
```

Initially I was getting the error:

```
Some events weren't counted. Try disabling the NMI watchdog:
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog
    perf stat ...
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog
```

So I tried this:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee  /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog
```

The error disappeared but Perf isn't counting the event:

```
 <not counted>      page-faults
```

I then tried again, removing the delay switch:

```
sudo perf stat -e page-faults my_app
```

and it works.

When using the delay switch, it does output `events enabled`.

Am I using this switch wrong/how can I begin profiling after N seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me with `perf version 6.3-4` on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux, with Linux kernel 6.4.9-arch1-1. In case the CPU matters for software events, it's an i7-6700k Skylake.

**Did your code exit before the 20 second delay was over?**  In that case, no events get counted for any counter.  I can reproduce your symptoms with a busy loop that exits after about 3.6 seconds on my system:

```
perf stat --delay=20000 -e task-clock,cycles,page-faults  \
    awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
```

It prints `Events disabled`, then `Events enabled` right as it's exiting, but `<not counted>` for both the hardware (`cycles`) and software (task-clock and page-faults) events.

Reducing the delay to `2000`ms (2 seconds), it does count for the second ~half of the 3.6 second run time:

```
$ perf stat --delay=2000 -e task-clock,cycles,page-faults  awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
Events disabled
Events enabled

 Performance counter stats for 'awk BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}':

          1,591.87 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
     6,208,241,402      cycles                           #    3.900 GHz                       
                 6      page-faults                      #    3.769 /sec                      

       1.591902071 seconds time elapsed

       3.590486000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

`awk` is single-threaded, but note the 1.59 sec elapsed vs. 3.59 sec "user" time: 2 seconds less, the time during which it wasn't counting.  I guess the user/sys times come from OS per-process counters, rather than `perf` looking at the wall-clock.

Comment: Hi Peter, I actually tested it using `-D 0` which counted events and `-D 1` which didn't count. I'm trying to get my perf version but `perf --version` returns `perf version`.

Comment: So `sudo perf stat --delay=1 -e task-clock,cycles,page-faults  awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'` does not count any events

Comment: @intrigued_66: Sounds like your system is broken but mine isn't.  I should have mentioned I'm using `perf version 6.3-4` on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux, with Linux kernel 6.4.9-arch1-1, on an i7-6700k Skylake in case the CPU matters for software events.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and a 1-2 year old Xeon. I installed Perf using `sudo apt install linux-tools-uname -r`

Comment: Okay, so I just updated my BIOS and after restarting when I tried to run Perf it couldn't find it, suggested I install `sudo apt install linux-tools-6.2.0-26-generic`. Did this, ran `perf` with delay, works!